# .htaccess on 000webhost not creating short urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

To cut a long story short, My urls look like this one

```
http://example.com/page.php?page_id=20
```

And what I want is Urls in this format

```
  http://example.com/page/20
```

This my .htaccess on 000webhost

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^page/(.*)[_+?]$ /page.php?page=news&id=$1 [QSA,R,L]
```

It is not working, I get 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  pattern is accepting urls like this

> http://example.com/page/20+

That is , I think not a valid url for this target url.

Try this

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^page/(.*)[_+?]?$ /page.php?page=news&id=$1 [QSA,L]
```